# Set a unique sessionID when aspx website loads

Tags: asp.net, session

I am working on an asp.net website, and I need to give a unique ID (e.g. GUID) to a user when they first visit the site, but have this value available all the time for the duration of their site visit.

I know that I could do this with a value in a session, but if that times out they would lose the assigned value.

I have tried the following but it changes each time a page loads:-

```
sid = ""
If HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID IsNot Nothing Then
    sid = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString
End If
```

Comment: *"but if that times out they would lose the assigned value"* - If the session times out then their "site visit" has ended.  Did you want to retain the value if they come back later from the same browser?  Setting a cookie should handle that.

Comment: It was more for when they first visit the site (as it doesnt a login) and there is a shop and I need to assign an id in a session to go against their activity (such as shopping) but if they take a break between their shopping and session times out they lose their basket contents.

I did consider cookies but if they are using browser with cookies disabled I have another problem there.